# Logical vs physical address program loaded into RAM, how re-mapping done?

Tags: cpu, memory-hardware

What are common primary mechanisms to "re-map" between physical memory in RAM, and the addresses used in a program before it is loaded into RAM? In image below for example, the LOAD 12 operation at address 01, must when program is running be loading the address 12 addresses from the "0 address" of the program (that in RAM could be anywhere I guess, depending on how much other shit is loaded into RAM. ) Is there something like a "0 equivalent", and then just a simple ADD operation to any address loaded, or, some other approach?

[image]

Comment: Of interest: [Relocation (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing))

Comment: Usually the loader will just change all the addresses in the instructions, AND/OR the instruction will say "read (instruction address + 11)" instead of just saying "read 11"

Comment: "other shit": is that intended ?

Comment: @GuyCoder: I don't think that the question is about code relocation, which comes "on top" virtual memory. This reference may mislead the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for taking the time to look at the comments in detail and note about them. I prefixed the comment with `Of interest:` for others, especially people new to programming may find the link of interest. It was not meant as a comment related directly to the question and why it is a comment with such a prefix. Another aspect of the `Of interest` prefix is that when I delete my old comments, comments with this prefix should either be left intact or checked in detail before deleting. Those without such a prefix I often delete without even reviewing before deleting.

Comment: @GuyCoder: people new to virtual memory may find the link misleading, especially those who ask "then just a simple ADD operation to any address loaded".

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is that the addresses stored in an executable are actually virtual addresses. All processes have a full set of page tables filled with mostly zeroes to prevent one process from accessing the memory space of another process. They also "see" a full virtual address space that is several hundreds of TB on x86-64. The physical allocations are only limited by the amount of physical RAM + swap space to back the allocations.

There are lots of approaches to allocate physical memory. On x86-64 Linux for example, the page struct is used to keep track of the memory allocated and not allocated. The page structures are kept in kernel space in the upper half of the virtual address space. This portion of the virtual address space is marked as "global" in the page tables so they are shared among all processes and are most often not flushed from the cache (including TLB and page cache).

The page structures are arranged in an efficient binary structure and an efficient algorithm is used to determine during runtime what page is free and which isn't. Afterwards, it is simply a matter of building the page tables of the process by allocating space for these in the physical memory.

Since the process sees a full virtual address space, only the page tables determine where its memory accesses/instruction fetching will end up. Most executables today have a starting address but are mostly position-independent because they use RIP-relative addressing by default to access the data segment and everything else is "local" and is accessed from within the stack by using a relative negative offset from RBP. The starting address is often 0x400000 for some reason.

When the executable is loaded from the hard-disk, it actually contains the virtual addresses at which it will be loaded. For the operating-system, it is simply a matter of resolving where it will land in physical memory and to build the page tables so that the accesses won't mess with another executable's address space.

Answer (score 1):

The program executes in its virtual address space, unaware of memory mapping. So READ 11 indeed reads from the virtual address 11.

Under the hood, address 11 is mapped somewhere in RAM (after the page has been mapped to RAM), and the exact location is irrelevant. It can change during program execution. How the mapping is done is the whole "virtual memory" story.

It is important to understand that the virtual spaces of all running programs do not interfere with each other, so they can use the same virtual locations.